# Can someone please tell me why my "name" class goes over my navigation menu on mobile please

Tags: html, css, class

When viewed at mobile and tablet, my "name" class will conflict with my burger menu.

https://johnblairgraphicart.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Can you explain in brief what you exactly want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .name {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 80%;
  }

}
```

this put your class at end of nav without top space and menu items after clicking work correctly

Answer (score 0):

`div` is by default block level elements which takes width 100%.
and you have given `top :50px` for `img`, which is overlapping irrespective of what ever is at bottom.

you can add

```
   .logo{
       width:41px;
       display:inline-block;
       margin-top:50px;
      } 
    .menu{
      width:calc(100% - 50px);
      display:inline-block;
      margin-top:50px;
     }
```